# ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 1 25]

Tags: text, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am running classification test on my articles and would like to perform leave one out CV as well, but after I run my function I get an error I do not quite understand. This is my code:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score, KFold
from scipy.stats import sem

bunch = load_files('corpus')

X = bunch.data
y = bunch.target

count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')
X_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_counts)

classifier = MultinomialNB().fit(X_tfidf, y)

def evaluate_cross_validation(clf, X, y, K):
    # create a k-fold cross validation iterator of k=N folds
    cv = KFold(len(y), K, shuffle=False, random_state=0)
    # by default the score used is the one returned by score >>> method of the estimator (accuracy)
    scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=cv)
    print scores
    print ("Mean score: {0:.3f} (+/-{1:.3f})").format(np.mean(scores), sem(scores))

clfs = [classifier]

for clf in clfs:
     evaluate_cross_validation(clf, X, y, 26)
```

However, I get this error and I do not understand what is happening:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-289-8f2a0d6aa294>", line 4, in <module>
    evaluate_cross_validation(clf, X, y, 26)

  File "<ipython-input-287-ecb52eb2fc76>", line 5, in evaluate_cross_validation
    scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=cv)

  File "/home/fledrmaus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1433, in cross_val_score
    for train, test in cv)

  File "/home/fledrmaus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 800, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):

  File "/home/fledrmaus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 658, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)

  File "/home/fledrmaus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 566, in _dispatch
    job = ImmediateComputeBatch(batch)

  File "/home/fledrmaus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.results = batch()

  File "/home/fledrmaus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 72, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]

  File "/home/fledrmaus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1531, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)

  File "/home/fledrmaus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 527, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr')

  File "/home/fledrmaus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 520, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)

  File "/home/fledrmaus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 176, in check_consistent_length
    "%s" % str(uniques))

ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 1 25]
```

Help would be appreciated.

thanks

**EDITED**:

I get values for y.shape but for X.shape just an error.

```
X.shape
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-305-270dd209b8a9>", line 1, in <module>
    X.shape

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

y.shape
Out[306]: (26,)
```

**EDITED II:**

Yes, I am operating with 26 articles. What I tried to do with my code was to transform articles into tfidf representations and then use it for my classifier. However, it seems that there is a disconnection between my `classifier` and my `def evaluate_cross_validation(clf, X, y, K)` function. I am trying to perform `leave-one-out CV`. My `X_tfidf.shape` is as follows:

```
X_tfidf.shape
Out[17]: (26, 3777)
```

**EDITED III:**

I would like to use this pipeline approach but it seems to me that it does not tfidf vectorize the articles:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')),
                     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
])
```

Cannot figure out how to modify this pipeline classifier to perform tfidf vectorization. :S

Comment: please post the values of `y.shape` and `X.shape`. Most likely they are wrong.

Comment: ok, `y` looks good if you have 26 training samples. Now what is len(X)? it should also be 26, i.e. a set of features for each target `y`. So `X[0]` re the features for the first sample and corresponds to the target `y[0]`, in the same way `X[1]->y[1], X[2]->y[2], ... , X[25]->y[25]`.

Comment: hmm, then it looks like my initial hypothesis with the shape is wrong as your `X_tfidf` looks good. What happens if you chose a smaller number of folds like `K=5`?

Comment: Just tested it and it does not work. Hm...If i use a pipeline for a classifier definition, then it works but it seems that it does not tfidf vectorize the articles. Processes them, generates mean score and binary classification output but its not accurate. I will update more my question. :S